# ASP.NET Web Forms element inside element

Tags: asp.net, html

I have now 3 hours of experience (tryence) in ASP.NET Web Forms. I'm so used to HTML that I need some help to get out of the box.

What I'm trying to do is a simple Element inside Element, but it keeps saying that "the element is not known".

What I need is:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>TEST</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying is:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>
        <asp:Panel runat="server">TEST</asp:Panel>
    </asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

This is not working and I would like to understand why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add elements inside asp:ListItems, you can only set the Value and Text property of them

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="Test"></asp:ListItem>
```

There's no real reason you couldn't use standard HTML controls and that will achieve what you want

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="testDiv" runat="server">TEST</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```